# ADOMD Connection String for OLAP Cube on SSAS using User Name and Password

Tags: silverlight, connection-string, ssas, olap, adomd.net

I want to establish a connection to **OLAP Cube** deployed on **SSAS** from a **Silverlight**  Application.
I'm using the **ADOMD library** and i want to know the format of the **Connection String**. I have the server URL, the Cube Name, User Name and Password.
In [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123468)  i didn't find how to to specify the **Authentification Parameters** ...

//From **SQL Server Management Studio** i'm using windows authentification to connect to the OLAP Cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty much the same as OLE DB. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdconnection.connectionstring